# Need help understanding LSTM graph from Neural Architecture Search

Tags: reinforcement-learning, lstm

In regards to this paper,
    [arXiv:1611.01578 [cs.LG]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01578)
the very last image, seen below, has a graph of a LSTM Cell (top left). I am trying to recreate it in python, but main thing that throwing me off.

Why are input and hidden state added in this diagram? Everywhere I see an LSTM diagram, the input and hidden state are concatenated, multiplied with a weight, and then bias is added. This matrix is then split into gates, and Each gate undergoes operations and you end up with hidden state and cell state. 
[image: Last Page of NAS paper]

Answer (score 1):

It is simply the dot product rewritten as addition where you add the  multiplication of rows by columns which equals the dot product of the concatenation.